# Setting default values on create and update in yii

Tags: yii2

I am trying to update some fields in yii 1.1 using the following rules, but it is not working.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       ['CreatedOn','default','value'=>time(),'isEmpty'=>true,'on'=>'insert'],
       ['CreatedBy','default','value'=>\Yii::$app->user->identity->id,'isEmpty'=>true,'on'=>'insert'],
       ['ModifiedOn','default','value'=>time(),'isEmpty'=>true,'on'=>'update'],
       ['ModifiedBy','default','value'=>\Yii::$app->user->identity->id,'isEmpty'=>true,'on'=>'update'],
    ];
}
```

I am looking to update `CreatedBy` and `CreatedOn` when inserting, and `ModifiedBy` and `ModifiedOn` when updating.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've taken a shot at making your question easier to follow by editing the grammar and moving some things around.

Comment: @nadeem do you really think that this is yii 1.1?

Comment: This seems to be for Yii2+

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz You're of course right. `Yii::$app` construction is used **only** in Yii2. Yii1 equivalent is `Yii::app()`. OP should decide, edit question and properly tag it.

Comment: edited. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [soju's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28981298/428543), with Yii2:

> By default, a model supports only a single scenario named `default`

You should therefore set the scenario manually in your controller i.e:

```
$model->scenario = 'insert';
```

You could also use `when` instead of `on` i.e:

```
['CreatedOn', 'default', 'value'=>time(), 'isEmpty'=>true, 'when'=>
    function($model) { return $model->isNewRecord; }
],
['ModifiedOn', 'default', 'value'=>time(), 'isEmpty'=>true, 'when'=>
    function($model) { return !$model->isNewRecord; }
],
```

An alternative to setting them in `rules()` would be to use [`beforeSave()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave%28%29-detail) to set them:

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if ($insert) {
        $this->CreatedBy = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $this->CreatedOn = time();
    } else {
        $this->ModifiedBy = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $this->ModifiedOn = time();
    }
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried first solution but still not working but i tried 2nd same (beforeSave()) solution as yours and fixed but i am still trying for first solution

Comment: @topher   `'isEmpty'=>true`  overrides the check if the field is empty .. and says it always is. this is not needed for the CreatedOn  rule.
the 'when' condition you use is also not needed in both cases.
See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to do it:

Behaviors:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_on',
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'modified_on',
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_DELETE => 'deleted_at',
                ],
                'value' => function () {
                    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                }
            ],
            [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by_id',
                'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by_id',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

If you need just a simple rule for **default** value,  this is enough:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['CreatedOn','default','value'=>time()],
            ['ModifiedOn','default','value'=>time(),'isEmpty'=>true],
        ...
        ]
    }
```

The `'isEmpty'=>true` option override  the default `isEmpty()` function and returns true (it is always seen as empty) dues it is always populated with `time()`

Answer (score 0):

For Yii2 version 2.0.8 from April 2016 I had an error with `'isEmpty'=>true` because according to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#handling-empty-inputs%20documentation) it expects a function so you must to do like this:`'isEmpty' => function ($value) {return true;}`.

When you use this solution you get a value for ModifiedBy even on create and I believe that was not an intention. It is possible to write isEmpty to return true in case of an update but I simply used 'when' because it is much more readable for me. So, my solution for rules in a model was :

```
    ['CreatedBy', 'default', 'value' => Yii::$app->user->id],
    ['ModifiedBy', 'default', 'value' => Yii::$app->user->id,
         'when' => function ($model) { return !$model->isNewRecord;}],
```

As a side note for this question is that for timestamps you should rely on database to fill them, CreatedOn with default value and a before update trigger for ModifiedOn.