# how to use required on insert validator for yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Can anyone have a suggestion about how to use `"on" => "insert"` validation in **yii2**?
I have used

```
array('field_name', 'required', 'on'=>'insert')
```

in **Yii1** but in **yii2** it does not check if I set

```
['field_name', 'required', 'on'=>'insert']
```

.
What is the problem here can you please explain?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should simply set your model's scenario before validation :

```
$model->scenario = 'insert';
```

Since with Yii2 :

> By default, a model supports only a single scenario named `default`

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

Answer (score 5):

First define the scenario:

```
// scenario is set as a property
$model->scenario = 'insert';
```

OR

```
// scenario is set through configuration
$model = new User(['scenario' => 'insert']);
```

Then you may specify the rule as:

```
// for single field
['field_name', 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],

// for multiple fields
[['field_name1','field_name2'], 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],
```

For more details check: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#validation-rules